# Take all links from XML sitemap, and put them into an array?

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have a sitemap with many urls. Something like:

```
<url>
<loc>
http://site.com/
</loc>
<priority>
0.50
</priority>
<changefreq>
daily
</changefreq>
<lastmod>
2011-07-27T06:58:53+00:00
</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://site.com/link
```

etc etc....

I need to get all the links in the sitemap, nothing else.

I've tried:

```
$links = file('sitemap.xml', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($links as $link) {
    echo $link;
}
```

Now that echos all the links and leaves all the `<loc>, <priority>` etc etc out but it still includes the change `frequency, lastmod` etc etc....

So the output looks like this:

```
http://site.com/ 11 0.50 12 daily 13 2011-07-27T06:58:53+00:00 14  15  16 http://site.com/page.html 17 0.40 18 daily 19 2011-07-
```

and so on....

I need to just get the links and put the into an array. Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$urls = array();  
$xml='sitemap.xml';
$DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DomDocument->loadXML("$xml"); // $DOMDocument->load('filename.xml');
$DomNodeList = $DomDocument->getElementsByTagName('from');

foreach($DomNodeList as $url) {
    $urls[] = $url->nodeValue;
}

//display it
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urls);
echo "</pre>";
```

Which returns the error: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1`

So i tried to test if it can even load the xml: I changed the xml file name to an invalid one (`$xml='sit___emap.xml';`)

I should of got an error saying it couldn't open the file, but instead it came up with the same error as before, with the correct filename set. So i don't think its the sitemap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't get [@AndreyKnupp's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348532/538216) to work.  Here's what works for me:

```
$urls = array();  

$DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DomDocument->load('filename.xml');
$DomNodeList = $DomDocument->getElementsByTagName('loc');

foreach($DomNodeList as $url) {
    $urls[] = $url->nodeValue;
}

//display it
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urls);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: works well, as I said (I commented in the code) the getElementsByTagName is much more affordable!

Comment: I tried this code, but i get the error: "Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1" I checked the xml file, and it does start with "<". any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I checked it with the validator, it was "well-formed". on two warnings: "Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document." "No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only." I will post the code i have used.

Comment: @Nav It's because you were using the `loadXML` function. It assumes the XML is in a string already.  I updated my answer to use the `load` function, which takes a filename as input.  Should work, mate.

Comment: Really hate to keep bothering you, but another error now shows up: "Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in line 9" which is the "$DOMDocument->load('filename.xml');" line. Again, i changed the filename and the same error popped up, so it looks like its not the xml file again. any ideas? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Nav It was my fault, actually.  It read `$DomDocument` instead of `$DOMDocument`.  Give that a shot.

Comment: ooo by the way, I also changed $DomNodeList to $DOMNodeList. I cant edit your answer. Just thought you might want to change it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the speed execution time using Levi Morrison (DOMDocument) method vs taoufiqaitali method (SimpleXML). The results where so amazing that I must share this with you.
My sitemap.xml had 11140 links in it (the sitemap of my webgallery).

Method 1 - DOMDocument -> 50.7 seconds execution time

```
$start = microtime(true);
$urls = array();  
$DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DomDocument->load('sitemap.xml');
$DomNodeList = $DomDocument->getElementsByTagName('loc');
foreach($DomNodeList as $url) {
    $urls[] = $url->nodeValue;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urls);
echo "</pre>";
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
echo $time_elapsed_secs . " seconds of execution time";
```

---

Method 2 - SimpleXML -> 0.129 seconds execution time

```
$start = microtime(true);
$urls = array();
$strXml = @file_get_contents('sitemap.xml');
$sitemap = @new SimpleXmlElement($strXml);
foreach($sitemap->url as $url) {
    $urls[] = strval($url->loc);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urls);
echo "</pre>";
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
echo $time_elapsed_secs . " seconds of execution time";
```

That is a HUGE difference. The SimpleXML method is almost 400 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this ..

```
<?php
$urls = array();  

$DOMDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DOMDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DOMDocument->loadXML($xml); // $DOMDocument->load('filename.xml');
$XPath = new DOMXPath($DOMDocument); // you can use getElementsByTagName

foreach($XPath->query('//url/loc') as $url) {
    // $urls[$url->nodeName] = $url->nodeValue;
    $urls[] = $url->nodeValue;
}

print_r($urls);
```

The output like:

```
Array
(
     [0] => http://site.com/
)
```

Comment: I think it should be `//urlset/url/loc`, but even with that change I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is

```js
$strXml = @file_get_contents($url);
if (false == $strXml)
    die('Could not open url. Check your spelling and try again');
$txt ="";
// So simple using SimpleXml
$sitemap = @new SimpleXmlElement($strXml);
foreach($sitemap->url as $url) {
    $txt .= $url->loc . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **any** XML parser? `DOMDocument`, `SimpleXML`, `xml_parse`

Answer (score 0):

Could also use simplexml

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
$links=$xml->xpath('//url/loc');
print_r($links);
```

Edit: may need to use `strval` when you use these array elements as it is still considered a SimpleXML object.